# Create image with transparent background using GDI+?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

I'm trying to create an image with a transparent background to display on a web page.
I've tried several techniques but the background is always black.
How can I create a transparent image and then draw some lines on it ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Call `Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)` to, well, clear the image. Don't forget to create it with a pixel format that has an alpha channel, e.g. `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`. Like this:

```
var image = new Bitmap(135, 135, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image)) {
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 135, 135);
}
```

Assumes you're `using` `System.Drawing` and `System.Drawing.Imaging`.

Edit: Seems like you don't actually need the `Clear()`. Just creating the image with an alpha channel creates a blank (fully transparent) image.

Comment: I guess I missed the overload on the Bitmap constructor. Unfortunately, I don't have the code available right now, I'll try this evening...

Comment: There was a little more than what you said to it, but I did a little research and got it to work. Thanks.

Comment: There was really more? I did exactly what you see in my code sample and it rendered fine with alpha channel.

Comment: The *more* had nothing to do with gdi. In fact, I'm using this to render an image to an ASP.Net page. The problem was that I was saving the image (in png format) directly into the response stream, but that doesn't work for pngs, I had to save it into a memory stream first.

Comment: In my case, I also need to do `image.MakeTransparent();`.

Comment: I just tried this code as is... background was as black as the ace of spades

Comment: @AndrewDuffy: I just pasted this code into LinqPad and it works as advertised (as long as you're importing the namespaces and set the background color of the results panel to non-white, because otherwise you won't see if it's actually transparent, and add a line image.Dump()). Try it, LinqPad is cool for simple experiments like this. What did you do with the image after creation, i.e. how did you notice it went black?

Answer (score 0):

This might help(something I threw together which sets the background of a Windows form to a transparent image:

```
private void TestBackGround()
    {
        // Create a red and black bitmap to demonstrate transparency.            
        Bitmap tempBMP = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBMP);
        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0, 0, tempBMP.Width, tempBMP.Width);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, tempBMP.Width, tempBMP.Width);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), tempBMP.Width, 0, 0, tempBMP.Width);
        g.Dispose();


        // Set the transparancy key attributes,at current it is set to the 
        // color of the pixel in top left corner(0,0)
        ImageAttributes attr = new ImageAttributes();
        attr.SetColorKey(tempBMP.GetPixel(0, 0), tempBMP.GetPixel(0, 0));

        // Draw the image to your output using the transparancy key attributes
        Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(this.Width,this.Height);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage);
        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tempBMP.Width, tempBMP.Height);
        g.DrawImage(tempBMP, destRect, 0, 0, tempBMP.Width, tempBMP.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);


        g.Dispose();
        tempBMP.Dispose();
        this.BackgroundImage = outputImage;

    }
```

Comment: It's too complexity and it's no need to do this way :)