# Drawing to and saving a png in vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

How could I create a bitmap which is initially completely transparent. I would then like to do some drawing to it, like g.drawImage() and then I would like to save it as a png. How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create image with transparent background using GDI+ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708860/create-image-with-transparent-background-using-gdi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(width, height)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
g.Clear(Color.Transparent)

''Perform Drawing here

bmp.Save("ZOMG AMAZING DRAWING.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Comment: i name all my files "ZOMG AMAZING DRAWING". i am on file number 23589252.